# why do tests fail at the prompt and pass in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

well - to answer my own question (in retrospect) - 'watch your six'; meaning that settings, definitions and tiny 'patches' from the past may sneak up on you!

In my case an environment variable which helps me *default-scope* all my models, was the culprit!

This this [gist](http://gist.github.com/1748930.git) documents me trying to prove that the exact same test passes in the rails console, when startet with

```
OX_ID=1 RAILS_ENV=test r c
```

that fails when run of the mill with **rake spec**, providing this output:

```
Running spec/models/user_spec.rb
....F


Failures:

  1) User should have 1 role through user_group
     Failure/Error: permission = Factory.create( :roleable, authorization: "all", ox: @ox, role: role )
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validering fejlede: Ox skal udfyldes
     # ./spec/factories/factories.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.01 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:56 # User should have 1 role through user_group
```

Being a total newcomer to Rspec testing, and not really that comfortable with the entire Rails Stack which BTW keeps getting taller and taller, I totally missed that my ENV["OX_ID"] on the command line, did not survive into the test environment (of cause, why/how should/could it?)

**To take away from this**

I finally added

```
y user.roles.to_sql
```

to my test (letting me see what kind of SQL Rails compiles) - and when I saw the output I did not believe my own eyes!

```
SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roleables` ON `roles`.`id` = `roleables`.`role_id`
  INNER JOIN `user_groups` ON `roleables`.`roleable_id` = `user_groups`.`id` AND `roleables`.`roleable_type`
  = 'UserGroup' INNER JOIN `user_groups_users` ON `user_groups`.`id` = `user_groups_users`.`user_group_id`
  WHERE `user_groups_users`.`user_id` = 3 AND (roles.ox_id=NULL) AND (roleables.ox_id=NULL)
  AND (user_groups.ox_id=NULL)
```

The `(roles.ox_id=NULL)` gave it all away! I was expecting it to say `roles.ox_id=1` and here it was!

Answer (score 0):

You are running rspec/shoulda code in the console, in the development environment, where the libraries are not loaded. I'm not exactly sure how you would go about doing that, but if you wanted to do a quick test in the console, you can just print out:

```
user.user_groups[0].roles.count == 1
```

Keeping it simple may be better in this case. Hope that helps.

Comment: no! (No), I'm not running in dev env. (No) it didn't help <:)